# Runtime Error 13 when assigning sheet to variable

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I created a subroutine in a seperate module for assigning some global variables in an Excel project I'm working on.  I'm assigning sheets to variables and there are 9 sheets/variables but only 1 errors on runtime 13 and when I check the locals window I see that the type assigned is "Worksheets" as opposed to "Variant/Object/Sheet#" as the rest of them do.  Here's some code:

```
Public Cover, Notes, HWIO, IntChn, FbChn, _ 
 DigFb, AnaFb, RemAlm, OGoL As Worksheets

Public Sub AssignVars()
 Set Cover = Sheets("1. Cover")
 Set Notes = Sheets("2. Notes")
 Set HWIO = Sheets("3. HW Input-Output")
 Set IntChn = Sheets("4. Internal Channels")
 Set FbChn = Sheets("5. Funct Block Channels")
 Set DigFb = Sheets("6. Digital Funct Blocks")
 Set AnaFb = Sheets("7. Analog Funct Blocks")
 Set OGoL = Sheets("OGOnline")
 Set RemAlm = Sheets("8. Remote Alarming")
End Sub
```

The error occurs on `Set OGoL = Sheets("OGOnline")`

Looking at the Locals I see that all of the variables except for OGoL have an sheet object assigned to them.  OGoL has "Worksheets" there.  It might be staring me in the face but I cannot tell why I'm getting a type mismatch, the sheet exists as named.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because you are assigning a *Worksheet* to a *Worksheets* variable.

The reason you do not encounter this on the previous seven variable initializations is because you have declared those variables as type variant.  In order to declare those variables as type Worksheet you must indicate so as such:

```
Public Cover As Worksheet, Notes As Worksheet, HWIO As Worksheet, _
IntChn As Worksheet, FbChn As Worksheet, DigFb As Worksheet, _
AnaFb As Worksheet, RemAlm As Worksheet, OGoL As Worksheet
```

Comment: Well hot dog, we have a weiner.  Thank you, I knew it was staring me in the face.  Solved all my problems!